# How to drive an induction hob coil from AC mains

Tags: power-electronics, mains, inductive, appliances

I have been looking into designing an induction hob circuit, but haven't really found complete answers to my questions.

As I understand it, it's important to take advantage of the natural resonant frequency of the system (which depends on the size of the saucepan) to ensure maximum power transfer to the saucepan. Presumably this means that the PWM driving the IGBTs should be at the correct frequency.

In one paper I read ([C2000 Dual VF Resonant Induction Cookers](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sprabt2/sprabt2.pdf)), it described changing the PWM frequency to provide different levels of heating power: a high frequency gave less power, while a lower frequency gave more power. But wouldn't this also result in working at a lower efficiency?

**Question 1:**
If I were to guess at the best way to drive the coil, it would be this: I would use a full bridge. The drive signal would be biphasic. A positive pulse would be followed by a recirculation time, then a negative pulse and another recirculation time. The pulse lengths would be adjusted according to the required power level. The microcontroller would be constantly adjusting the PWM frequency searching for the maximum efficiency. Is that right, or is there a better way?

[image: Full bridge induction hob]

[image: Full bridge biphasic waveforms]

**Question 2:** Does the PWM frequency affect the efficiency of power transfer, or just the actual power delivered?

**Question 3:** Is the smoothing capacitor at the AC input really necessary? Couldn't the microcontroller measure the dynamic AC voltage, and adjust the PWM on-time accordingly for each PWM cycle? Am I correct in thinking that the capacitor there affects the power factor?

Comment: Q3 - the C after the bridge rectifier is small, works at the output frequency, not the mains frequency

Comment: @Neil_UK - Aah, that makes much more sense.

Comment: For Q1, you could make an argument that MOSFETs (SiC ones, most likely, considering the high voltage and current) may be superior to IGBTs, but that's getting into the weeds a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question 1:
> In the picture there's a constant load so the performance will be predictable.

In the text the load is a cooktop so the load will be variable and sensing the load
and varying the output to suit seems like a good idea.  efficiency is always a good goal mainly because it keeps the circuit cooler, which makes it last longer, and that reduces waste.

You may find that the frequency is constrained to be inside some ISM band (eg 25Khz)  by using ISM band you get more lee-way on EMI.

> Question 2: Does the PWM frequency affect the efficiency of power transfer

If the output inductor saturates efficiency will tank. I guess that really means that PWM duration effects efficiency.  but duration is limited by frequency, so yes basicallty.

> Question 3: Is the smoothing capacitor at the AC input really necessary?

It's only needed if you don't want to run at full power or zero power. so yes again.
this is because the current through the link inductor needs to go somewhere when the transistors are not passing current from top to bottom.

Comment: Question 1 is now a question.

Comment: Why does current need to go through the link inductor? You mean, just for the short period when the transistors turn off, and the magnetic field in the link inductor is collapsing?

Comment: you can't suddenly stop the current in an inductor it's like trying to catch a bullet.